# Posting variable from JavaScript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have been trying to post a JS variable into PHP with using the $.ajax function. It didn't work though. The situation is like this: There is a page with a submit button, if I the button is clicked it loads a JS function which has confirm() in it. If I click OK (if confirm is true) it should execute the post action on another php page.

```
   function sure () {
  var conf = confirm(text here);
$.ajax({
  url: 'action.php',
  type: Post
  data: {istrue: conf};
  })
```

.      }

Answer (score 1):

It's jQuery related than JavaScript.

There is not `type` param in `$.ajax`. You have to use `method` param instead.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: 'action.php',
  data: {istrue: conf}
})
```

Comment: You might want to comment a bit on what you changed, and why such a change was made. Code-only answers aren't really useful.